# Getting error when i changed my domain from poetnpoetry.com to www.poetnpoetry.com

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, domain-name

I am getting error (in CodeIgniter) when I change my domain name form poetnpoetry.com to www.poetnpoetry.com. This is error which I am receiving when I am trying to login from AJAX or by submit the form.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://poetnpoetry.com/login/ulogin. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'www.poetnpoetry.com'. Origin 'http://www.poetnpoetry.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I changed my domain from poetnpoetry.com by using `.htaccess` file:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

#This bit rewrites your host name to include www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.poetnpoetry\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.poetnpoetry.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "www.poetnpoetry.com"

#This bit does the codeigniter magic
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

your ajax call is base on **base_url().**

```
config.php

$config['base_url ']="base url here";
```

And it is not based on www as well

Comment: why you need to change the domain name.? It is not a matter whether it has www or not, in codeigniter

Comment: Thanx its not working i thought its better idea for SEO